# iPhone VoiceOver accessibility setting crashes video recording

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I've finally nailed down a bug that crashes a `UIImagePickerController` when recording video. When the iPhone's VoiceOver accessibility setting is enabled, the recorder crashes without fail when calling `presentModalViewController`.

I've been unsuccessful so far in coming up with a workaround. Has anyone else experienced this and been able to fix it?

Comment: What OS version? What OS versions is it not present in? Have you considered filing a bug report?

Comment: I'm encountering the same, but only when showsCameraControls is set to NO.

Comment: You do get two technical support incidents with your iOS developer account. This does sound like a time for it. If there is a workaround, the guys at Apple will know.

Comment: @james Two questions: when you presentModalViewController, are you using animated:NO or animated:YES? Also, are you using showsCameraControls = NO?

Comment: @kamens, I'm using `animated:YES` and `showCameraControls = NO`

Comment: @james Just as a test -- if you move the ".showsCameraControls = NO" line into the completion block of presentViewController, does it work for you? It does for me (but I don't love this solution). Similarly, it works for me if .showsCameraControls = YES (although this obviously isn't a good workaround).

Comment: @james Also, what exact line are you using to set your picker's .mediaTypes?

Comment: Can you put up a stack trace of the crash?

Comment: @kamens and quellish, see answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @kamens mentioned in the comments above, a workaround is to include `camera.showsCameraControls = NO` in a completion block when presenting the modal view controller, like this:

```
[controller presentViewController:self animated:YES completion:^{self.showsCameraControls = NO;}];
```

However, with this solution, the camera controls flash momentarily as the camera is presented, then they disappear. Obviously not ideal when the controls really need to be hidden. The other workaround is to set `camera.showsCameraControls = OFF`... even less ideal.

---

@quellish, this is the output from the crash:

```
*** -[PLCameraToggleButton setAccessibilityValue:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x4a330b0
```

@kamens, here is the code I'm using to set the `mediaTypes` and `captureMode`:

```
tmpCamera.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie];
tmpCamera.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModeVideo;
```

Comment: Superb! After spending 1 complete day I found your answer. Thanks a lot, it worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

As @james mentions, this happens in iOS 5.1 when:

- Using `picker.showsCameraControls = NO`
- Using `animated:NO` in your call to `[viewController presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];`
- The VoiceOver accessibility option is enabled.

...*and*, significantly, when only specifying movies as the media types accepted by picker:

- picker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie];

---

However, I was able to fix this by changing the above mediaTypes line to:

```
picker.mediaTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:picker.sourceType];
```

...which works fine given that the default camera controls are hidden and I can programmatically control whether to start recording a video or take a picture.

I don't claim to understand the cause of this crash.